# Error in Spark streaming with Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

When I launch a streaming task through `spark-submit` , I get warning messages about Kafka properties being invalid:

```
VerifiableProperties: Property auto.offset.reset is overridden to largest
VerifiableProperties: Property enable.auto.commit is not valid.
VerifiableProperties: Property sasl.kerberos.service.name is not valid
VerifiableProperties: Property key.deserializer is not valid
...
VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to ....
```

The property `zookeeper.connect` is picked up properly.

How is it possible that following property

`kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");`

...be treated as invalid?

In my java code, I've provided kafka parameters in a HashMap and pass this to `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream()` API. I don't know why the properties are warned as invalid.

When I try to print the `JavaPairInputDStream` as 
    `directStream.print();`

It throws exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket had likely been closed.
```

the jaas.conf is provided to the spark-submit command as

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Djava.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf"
```

private key, public key are included in the spark-submit command as

```
--files jaas.conf,privatekey,publickey
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using both the receiver based stream in same class for testing as

```
JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, byte[]> receiverStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(...);
```

...and direct stream as

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, byte[]> directStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...);
```

Found out some required changes from here:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/6332/how-to-read-from-a-kafka-topic-using-spark-streami.html

Looks like, only receiver based stream works with the given software stack versions.

However, the warning messages from `VerifiableProperties` is still coming. **That is still unresolved**.